# How to redirect call from one Asterisk server to another to specific extension? IAX2

Tags: asterisk

I got 2 Asterisk servers and i want to connect them with IAX2 protocol. Somehow i manage with this and i can redirect calls from one server to another on particular SIP device.
Like this.
`exten = _9XXX,1,Dial(IAX2/serverA/${EXTEN:1},30,r)`
The question is how to redirect call not to SIP device, but to extension on *serverA*.

Answer (score 0):

On server A you should put call in context like this:

```
[incoming-from-b]
exten => 1000,1,Dial(SIP/1000,,o)
```

On server B you should call to
IAX2/serverA/1000

You can use variables including EXTEN, but idea will be the same.